# Convert timestamp to date in DAX with DirectQuery

Tags: powerbi, directquery

I want to convert a `Timestamp` column to date column in my table. I tried to create a measure with DAX:

```
Date = FORMAT('my_table'[Timestamp], "dd/mm/yyyy")*1
```

and caught error:

```
A single value for column 'Timestamp' in table 'my_table' cannot be determined. This can happen when a measure formula refers to a column that contains many values without specifying an aggregation such as min, max, count, or sum to get a single result.
```

but I do not need aggregation here I just need to convert datetime to date.

Timestamp column looks like this:

[image]

---

Tried:

```
Date = FORMAT(MIN('my_table'[Timestamp]), "dd/mm/yyyy")*1
```

which gives a weird date format, as I tried to inspect a visual using "show as a table":
[image]

Comment: You probably want to use a Calculated Column, not a Measure.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Mankarse, would that work for DirectQuery?

Comment: How do you intend to use this date field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a **calculated column** not a *measure*.

You can simply duplicate the timestamp column and then change the column data type to Date.

```
Date = 'my_table'[Timestamp]
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, I forgot to mention that I'm using DirectQuery data. It caught error `This query contains transformations that can't be used for DirectQuery.` when I tried to create a new column.

Answer (score 2):

Can you please try this below **Measure**-

```
Date = FORMAT(MIN('my_table'[Timestamp]), "dd/mm/yyyy")*1
```

Comment: Hi thank you for the answer. I tried and it seems like the date format is wrong, please see edited question.

Comment: Hi @nilsinelabore, this is because the last part *1 I guess. Just remove that part and try again.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I tried to remove *1 but I don't think it's what I wanted. I want to convert timestamp to date so I can count the events in each day but this method seems to extract only one day...